# Getting high precision values from qnorm in the tail

Tags: r, normal-distribution

### The problem

I am looking for high precision values for the normal distribution in the tail `(1e-10 and 1 - 1e-10)`, as the R package that I am using sets any number which is out of this range to these values and then calls the `qnorm` and `qt` function.

What I have noticed is that the `qnorm` implementation in R is not symmetric when looking at the tails. This is quite surprising to me, as it is well known that this distribution is symmetric, and I have seen implementations in other languages that are symmetric. I have checked the `qt` function and it is also not symmetric in the tails.

Here are the results from the qnorm function:

```
x       qnorm(x)                qnorm(1-x)              qnorm(1-x) + qnorm(x)
1e-2    -2.3263478740408408     2.3263478740408408      0.0 (i.e < machine epsilon)
1e-3    -3.0902323061678132     3.0902323061678132      0.0 (i.e < machine epsilon)
1e-4    -3.71901648545568       3.7190164854557084      2.8421709430404007e-14
1e-5    -4.2648907939228256     4.2648907939238399      1.014299755297543e-12
1e-10   -6.3613409024040557     6.3613408896974208      -1.2706634855419452e-08
```

It is quite clear that at a value of `x` close to 0 or 1, this function breaks down. Yes, in "normal" use this isn't a problem, but I am looking at fringe cases and multiplying small probabilities by very large values, in which case the error `(1e-08)` becomes a large value.

Note: I have tried this with `1-x` and with entering the actual number `0.00001` and `0.99999` and the accuracy issue is still there.

### The questions

Firstly, is this a known problem with the `qnorm` and `qt` implementations? I could not find anything in the documentation, the algorithm is supposed to be accurate 16 digits for p values from `10^-314`as described in the [Algorithm AS 241](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347330?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) paper.

Quote from R doc:

> Wichura, M. J. (1988) Algorithm AS 241: The percentage points of the normal distribution. Applied Statistics, 37, 477–484.
>
> which provides precise results up to about 16 digits.

If the R code implements the 7 digit version, why does it claim 16 digits? Or is it "accurate" but the original algorithm is not symmetric and wrong?

If R does implement both versions of [Algorithm AS 241](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347330?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) can I turn the 16 digit version on?

Or, is there a more accurate version of `qnorm` in R?
Or, another solution to my problem where I need high precision in the tails for quantile functions.

#### R version

```
>version 
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.2                         
year           2016                        
month          10                          
day            31                          
svn rev        71607                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch
```

Comment: Probably better asked on R-dev mailing list.

Comment: Good idea @Spacedman, I am not an avid R user and wasn't aware of this list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out (as noted by Spencer Graves in [his response](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-April/074069.html) to this same question on the R-devel list-serve) that `qnorm()` **does** in fact perform as advertised. It's just that, to get highly accurate results in the distribution's upper tail, you'll need to avail yourself of the function's `lower.tail` argument.

Here's how do that:

```
options(digits=22)

## For values of p in [0, 0.5], specify lower tail probabilities 
qnorm(p = 1e-10)                      ## x: P(X <= x) == 1e-10
# [1] -6.3613409024040557

## For values of p in (0.5, 1], specify upper tail probabilities
qnorm(p = 1e-10, lower.tail=FALSE)    ## x: P(X > x)  == 1e-10     (correct approach)
# [1] 6.3613409024040557
qnorm(p = 1 - 1e-10)                  ## x: P(X <= x) == 1-(1e-1)  (incorrect approach)
# [1] 6.3613408896974208
```

The problem is that `1-1e-10` (for example) is subject to floating point rounding errors, such that it isn't really the same distance from `1` (the upper end of the interval) as `1e-10` is from `0` (the lower end of the interval). The underlying problem (it's [R-FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)!) becomes obvious when put in a more familiar guise:

```
1 - (1 - 1e-10) == 1e-10
## [1] FALSE
```

Finally, here's a quick confirmation that `qnorm()` provides accurate (or at least symmetrical) results out to the values claimed in its help file:

```
qnorm(1e-314)
## [1] -37.906647423565666
qnorm(1e-314, lower.tail=FALSE)
## [1] 37.906647423565666

## With this failing in just the way (and for just the reason) you'd now expect
qnorm(1-1e-314)
# [1] Inf
1 == (1-1e-314)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for adding Spencers's answer here @Josh. I'm aware of this floating point error, but I thought that the distance from 0 to 1e-10 would be the same as that from 1 to 0.9999999999; if I enter 0.9999999999 explicitly. But I see that due to the way the function is coded this is not true.

Comment: @Sheldon Here's the reason they can't be the same distance from their endpoints. First off, no value of the form `(0.1)^n` can be absolutely precisely represented by a floating point number. One can only get closer and closer by adding additional binary digits. In the case of the value `1e-10`, those limited digits start getting used up way over at the right hand side of `0.0000000001`, whereas for `0.9999999999`, you had to start 'using up' your limited number of binary digits over to the left with the first `9`, leaving many fewer for the approximation to continue beyond the final `9`. HTH!

Comment: How do i ensure that `pnorm()` does not under/overflow? I tried this `c(37.99,-37.99) |> pnorm(log.p = TRUE) |> qnorm(log.p = TRUE)` which outputs
`#> [1]  37.98999999998493848352 -37.99000000000000909495`, perhaps close enough, but not perfect. I guess my problem is that I can't get `pnorm(37.99)` to produce a value less than 1, and nor does `pnorm(-37.99, lower.tail = FALSE)` do it.